# Gatsbyjs, webpack - "onload" tag is striped in build process

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I want to implement https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/ for my scss files (maybe someone has ready solution?). But i have problem and not sure if this is related to gatsbyjs or to the webpack build process in general.

In the gatsbyjs's I want to "preload" css, but the "onload" tag is removed from output html file, as if this tag was filtered somewhere but I can't find where and how to fix it.

```
export const onPreRenderHTML = ({ getHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {

    let hc = getHeadComponents();

    hc.forEach(el => {
        if (el.type === "style") {
            el.type = "link";
            el.props["href"] = el.props["data-href"];
            el.props["rel"] = "preload";
            el.props["as"] = "style";
            el.props["onload"]="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet';"
            el.props['ANY_OTHER_TAG'] = 'works as expected'; 
        }
    })
}
```